# How do I access the an assets subdirectory with Directory in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, directory, io

I am working on an app in Flutter where I will have to find filenames that start with specific keywords in a directory (and then do things with those filenames subsequently). However, I am encountering trouble accessing the directory itself.

I have an 'assets' folder in the root directory of my project, as many online sources recommended, and a subdirectory in that directory. I include this subdirectory in my pubspec.yaml in the format 'assets/[subdirectory name]', and can generally access its contents with 'assets/[subdirectory name]/[filename]' with methods like loadString. However, when I try to access the directory like this: Directory('assets/subdirectory/'), a FileSystemException no such directory error is thrown. I have tried the usual combination of adding './' or removing the final slash, to no avail.

Are Directory filepaths relative to something else? Is there a better way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Directory()` operates on the filesystem. You can't access assets with it because assets are bundled with the app during the build process.

> During a build, Flutter places assets into a special archive called the asset bundle that apps read from at runtime.

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images#asset-bundling

To get a list of assets in the app, you can use the undocumented generated file `AssetManifest.json` which contains a map of all bundled assets:

```dart
final assetsManifest = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('AssetManifest.json');
final assets = json.decode(assetsManifest).keys;
```

Another option (perhaps cleaner, since AssetsManifest.json is AFAIK indeed undocumented and might change in future versions) would be to simply make your own list of assets and save it as another asset (JSON file).